# Python. list.pop() based on index

Tags: python, list

I was working with list in python and I need to remove non-true values.

Can someone explain why here I get index out of range error:

```
    for n in range(len(lst)-1):                  #index outside the range
        if not bool(lst[n]):
            lst.pop(n)
    return lst
```

It is kind of work with while loop

```
def compact(lst):
    while n < len(lst):
        if not bool(lst[n]):
            lst.pop(n)
        n+=1
        print(n)

    return lst
```

But in this case loop will skip some items.

function is called like:
`compact([0, 1, 2, '', [], False, (), None, 'All done'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete an element, all the elements after it renumber: the `n+1`th element becomes `n`th element, etc. But you progress to the next `n` anyway. This is why you are skipping some elements.

In the first snippet, you pre-construct the list of indices to iterate over; but as the list shortens, some of the later indices will not exist any more.

In the second snippet, you compare with the actual length of the list on each iteration, so you never get an invalid index.

Also note that `bool` is not needed whenever you are evaluating a condition, as it is implicitly applied in such a context.

In order to do this correctly, you have two choices:

- iterate from *end* of the list *backwards*. If you delete an element, the elements *in front of it* do not get renumbered.

  ```
  for n in range(len(lst) - 1, -1, -1):
      if not lst[n]:
          lst.pop(n)
  ```
- using the `while` method, make sure to *either* increment `n` (moving `n` closer to the end of the list), *or* delete an element (moving the end of the list closer to `n`); never both at the same time. This will ensure no skipping.

  ```
  n = 0
  while n < len(lst):
      if not lst[n]:
          lst.pop(n)
      else:
          n += 1
  ```

The third option is to avoid the index loop altogether, and do it more pythonically, generating a new list using a comprehension with a filtering condition, or `filter`.

```
new_lst = list(filter(bool, lst))
```

or

```
new_lst = [e for e in lst if e]
```

or, if you really want to change the original list, replace its content like this:

```
lst[:] = filter(bool, lst)
```

Comment: Thanks. It actually hit me with a while loop the moment I hit submit question. My solution is after pop() I have to reset the loop  (n=0) so it start over.

Answer (score 0):

Index out of range error:
`lst.pop(n)` This will pop element from the list but `for n in range(len(lst)-1)` will still loop through the lst assuming same length as original.

To avoid this start loop from last index in reverse order so that even after pop values will still be present for indexes yet to be read.

```
   def compact(lst):
    for n in range(len(lst)-1,-1,-1):                  
        if not bool(lst[n]):
            lst.pop(n)
    return lst

    ls = [0, 1, 2, '', '',[], False, (), None, 'All done','']
    print(compact(ls))

    # Output:
    # [1, 2, 'All done']
```